# How to change file loading and transfer capacity in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I added the following to my `.htaccess` file, but still can't upload the file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 256M
php_value post_max_size 256M
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value max_input_time 600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your `config.php` file.

```
@ini_set('upload_max_filesize' , '256M');
@ini_set('post_max_size', '256M');
@ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
@ini_set('max_execution_time', '600');
@ini_set('max_input_time', '600');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `set_time_limit` to wp-config.php

```
set_time_limit( 600 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is correct answer for your question
Refer to [following URL](https://kinsta.com/blog/increase-max-upload-size-wordpress/):

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your `config.php` file.

```
@ini_set('upload_max_filesize' , '256M');
@ini_set('post_max_size', '256M');
@ini_set('max_input_time', '600');
```

Answer (score 0):

With a code or text editor, add the following code to your existing or new `php.ini` file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 128M
```

Answer (score 0):

Create or Modify the `.user.ini` File

> If your hosting provider has locked down the global PHP settings, they may have configured the server to work with `.user.ini` files instead of `php.ini` files.

```
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 128M
```

Answer (score 0):

**Increase the Max Upload File Size in Nginx**

On an Nginx server, you can find the php.ini file at `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`. Depending on which PHP version you’ve installed, the exact path may vary slightly.

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 128M
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the WordPress `‘upload_size_limit’` Filter

Below is an example of this filter in action from WordPress contributor Drew Jaynes. It defines the upload size limit for all non-admin roles.

```
/**
* Filter the upload size limit for non-administrators.
*
* @param string $size Upload size limit (in bytes).
* @return int (maybe) Filtered size limit.
*/
function filter_site_upload_size_limit( $size ) {
// Set the upload size limit to 10 MB for users lacking the 'manage_options' capability.
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
// 10 MB.
$size = 1024 * 10000;
}
return $size;
}
add_filter( 'upload_size_limit', 'filter_site_upload_size_limit', 20 );
```